# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' when uploading to PhpMyAdmin database table

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly, I am quite new to PHP so there may be errors in my code which aren't related to this question (which may have been answered elsewhere).

**The problem**: I am trying to upload a prepared statement into a table in PhpMyAdmin (XAMPP), hosted locally, to create user accounts. Whenever I try to create a new user I receive this message...

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to 
database 'coursework,root'
```

I have already tried multiple solutions that worked for others such as changing my servername to 127.0.0.1 from localhost and checking

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

is set to true for both my config.inc.php and config.sample.inc files. However, this has not change the result.

This is the code in the config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Here's my code for my php file

```
<?php

$msg = "";
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = '';
$dbname = "coursework";

if (isset($_POST['RegisterBtn'])) {

    $Password = ($_POST['PasswordInput']);
    $CPassword = ($_POST['ConfirmPasswordInput']);

    if ($Password != $CPassword) {
        $msg = ("Passwords do not match, Please try again");
    } else {

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname,$username,$password");

            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            //Preparing the sql and binding new account parameters
            $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO userlogin (Forname,Surname,Email_Address,Password)VALUES(:Forname,:Surname,:Email_Address,:Password)");
            $statement->bindParam(':Forename', $Forename);
            $statement->bindParam(':Surname', $Surname);
            $statement->bindParam(':Email_Address', $EmailAddress);
            $statement->bindParam(':Password', $hash);

            //inserting user data
            $Forename = ($_POST['ForenameInput']);
            $Surname = ($_POST['SurnameInput']);
            $EmailAddress = ($_POST['EmailInput']);
            $hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

            //executing the statement
            $statement->execute();
            $msg = "Your account has been created...";

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $msg = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Any answers that aid my understanding are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Changing parameters for `phpMyAdmin` only effect `phpMyAdmin` and remember thats a tool written in PHP AND NOT MYSQL which is the database you and `phpMyAdmin` are trying to access

Comment: Is the XAMPP documentation to blame for people regularly confusing phpMyAdmin for the actual database?

Comment: @mario I know its not PC to say it out loud,but. No the problem is that Apache/PHP/MySQL are all free. Anybody can pick them up and start hacking away without the first clue about what they are doing or what these tools actually are. _And they do as you can tell from the questions we get in here_

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for your help. It's important to remember that everyone has to start somewhere...

Comment: Harry Yup I agree, I started there as well. But it really helps get a decent answer, if you use the right terms when asking a question. Although I did spend a couple of weeks with a couple of books and some online tutorials before I bothered anyone else with what I didnt know. It was the bad old days when online assistance was unavailable

Comment: Oh and it is not cool, amending a question once an answer has been given and accepted

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I amended an error unrelated to this question. Surely you see the logic in that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this line is wrong.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname,$username,$password");
```

Try this.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);
```